# c# Using skip and take on a class derived from List

Tags: c#, list, derived-class, skip

I have the following class:

```
public class SearchFlightInfoCollList: List<SearchFlightInfoColl>
    {
        public bool TwoWays { get; set; }
        public int TotPages = 1;
        public int CurPage = 1;
    }
```

Now I would like to skip some elements in the collection and take others such as:

```
mySearchCollList.skip((curpage-1)*4).take(4);
```

But the result of the operation is not a SearchFlightInfoCollList anymore.
What can i do to discard some items and take others, without having to loop myself through the collection, and ending up with the same type as before?

Comment: You need to implement that yourself.

Comment: This is one reason why derived lists are not often used. Easier to create a class that has a `List<T>` property along with the additional one you need.

Comment: you need to create constructor for SearchFlightInfoCollList like: `SearchFlightInfoCollList(IQueryable<SearchFlightInfoColl> flights)`

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, casting back to your original class wouldn't do you much good. I think the `TotPages` and `CurPages` would need to be updated when you call those methods.

So, you would have to implement the `Skip` and `Take` methods.
The originals are extension methods, so no need to override or anything.

ex:

```
public class SearchFlightInfoCollList: List<SearchFlightInfoColl>
{
    public void Skip(int count)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

You lose a lot of the flexibility of Linq and the generic classes if you do insist on keeping the `SearchFlightInfoCollList` instance around. I would suggest maybe making a container/facade class that contains a `List<T>` and has additional properties.

Comment: I have removed the derived class and replaced with one having a List internally. It was quite easy refactoring.